# Can I use Solr term component with filtering on non-term fields

Tags: solr

http://localhost:8080/search/terms?terms.prefix=ab&terms.fl=text&terms.sort=count

I have the above terms query which works as I expect. Returns all the terms from the "text" field that have a certain prefix, sorted by count.

I want to return only the terms where another field "language" is "en" can I add such a filter to a terms query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't filter while accessing the indexed terms within a field through the `TermsComponent`. That's one of the limitations you face when you make auto suggestions for example. If you're making auto-suggestions, one of the ways that supports filtering is based on a facet and the prefix parameter like explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_prefix_.28term_suggest.29).

Comment: Thanks I'll give facets a try.